# Resample pandas df with multiple groupbys so each condition has the same number of total days of data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resample

I have been going round in circles with this and haven't been able to figure it out.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "person_id": ["1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3"],
    "event": ["Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert2", "Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert2", "Alert2", "Alert2", "Alert2", "Alert2"],
    "mode": ["Manual", "Manual", "Auto", "Manual", "Auto", "Auto", "Auto", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Auto", "Manual"],
    "date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05"]
}
)

df
```

| index | person_id | event | mode | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-03 |
| 3 | 1 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-03 |
| 4 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-03 |
| 5 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-03 |
| 6 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-04 |
| 7 | 2 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-04 |
| 8 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-04 |
| 9 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-04 |
| 10 | 3 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-05 |
| 11 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-05 |

What I want is the count of *each possible combination* per possible day (the minimum date would be the first date appearing in the dataset, in this case 2020-01-01 and the maximum date would be the last date appearing in the dataset, in this case 2020-01-05). For example, in the case of the df above, the output would look like this:

| index | person_id | event | mode | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 13 | 1 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 14 | 1 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 15 | 1 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 16 | 1 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 17 | 1 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 18 | 1 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 19 | 1 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 20 | 2 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 21 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 22 | 2 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 23 | 2 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 24 | 2 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 25 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 26 | 2 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 27 | 2 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 28 | 2 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 29 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-03 | 2 |
| 30 | 2 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 31 | 2 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 32 | 2 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 33 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| 34 | 2 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| 35 | 2 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 36 | 2 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 37 | 2 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 38 | 2 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 39 | 2 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 40 | 3 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 41 | 3 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 42 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 43 | 3 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 44 | 3 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 45 | 3 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 46 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 47 | 3 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| 48 | 3 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 49 | 3 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 50 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 51 | 3 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| 52 | 3 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 53 | 3 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 54 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-04 | 2 |
| 55 | 3 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 56 | 3 | Alert1 | Manual | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 57 | 3 | Alert1 | Auto | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| 58 | 3 | Alert2 | Manual | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| 59 | 3 | Alert2 | Auto | 2020-01-05 | 1 |

Importantly, each combination should have the exact same number of unique datetimes at the end, so if I run the following line of code:

`df_summarized.groupby(['person_id', 'event', 'mode'])['date'].nunique().reset_index()`

The result should clearly show that each combination has 5 unique days of data.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you need to do is first create a finite set of all possible combinations, and then count their occurences.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

# Create the original DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "person_id": ["1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3"],
    "event": ["Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert2", "Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert1", "Alert2", "Alert2", "Alert2", "Alert2", "Alert2"],
    "mode": ["Manual", "Manual", "Auto", "Manual", "Auto", "Auto", "Auto", "Manual", "Manual", "Manual", "Auto", "Manual"],
    "date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-05"]
})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

person_ids = df['person_id'].unique()
events = df['event'].unique()
modes = df['mode'].unique()
dates = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='D')

all_combinations = pd.DataFrame(list(product(person_ids, events, modes, dates)), columns=['person_id', 'event', 'mode', 'date'])

count_df = df.groupby(['person_id', 'event', 'mode', 'date']).size().reset_index(name='count')

result = all_combinations.merge(count_df, on=['person_id', 'event', 'mode', 'date'], how='left').fillna(0)
result.reset_index(drop=True, inplace
```